# React - API fetches - 2nd fetch uses data from 1st fetch?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to programming and have been learning React for a few weeks. I decided to create a weather app to practice what I've learned so far.
I created a Button.js file, where I can enter a zip code. The zip code is then used to setZip in Weather.js.
I am using the zip to fetch lat/long, which I would like to use (the lat/long) in another fetch. But when the 2nd fetch runs, it uses the previous lat/long, not the newly set lat/long.
For example:
If I enter 10001, the app uses lat/long from 90210 (which is what state started with). Then if I enter 99501, the app uses the lat/long from 10001.
It's like the 2nd fetch is always one step behind.
But even the console.log I have right below the 1st fetch shows the previous lat/long.
Thank you for your help.

Weather.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import Button from "./Button"
  
function Weather() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const [maxTemp, setMaxTemp] = useState([])
  const [lat, setLat] = useState("34")
  const [long, setLong] = useState("-118")
  const [zip, setZip] = useState("90210")

  useEffect(()=>{ 
    setLoading(true)
       fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/zip?zip="+ zip +",US&appid={api}")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
      setLat(result.lat)
      setLong(result.lon)
      console.log(lat)
      console.log(long)
      console.log(zip)
      console.log(result)
      return fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat="+ lat +"&lon="+ long +"&units=imperial&exclude=current,minutely,hourly,alerts&appid={api}")
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
      setLoading(false)
      setMaxTemp(data.daily[0].temp.max)
      console.log(lat)
      console.log(long)
      console.log(data)
    })
  }, [zip])  

  if(loading === true){
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  } else return( 
    <div>
    <Button zip={setZip} /> <br />
    High: {Math.round(maxTemp)} 
    </div>
  )
}

export default Weather
```

Button.js

```
import React, {useState} from "react"

function Button(props) {
  
  const [zip, setZip] = useState([])

  const handleSubmit = (event) => { 
    console.log(zip)
    props.zip(`${zip}`)
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  return(
    <div>
    <input placeholder="Zip Code" type="number" min="0" max="99999" value={zip} onChange={(e) => setZip(e.target.value)} />
    <br />
    <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Button
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the state is being set and immediately available, you'll need to use the value returned from the first API call.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import Button from "./Button"
  
function Weather() {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [maxTemp, setMaxTemp] = useState([])
    const [lat, setLat] = useState("34")
    const [long, setLong] = useState("-118")
    const [zip, setZip] = useState("90210")
    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true)
        fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/zip?zip=" + zip + ",US&appid={api}")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(result => {
                const {lat, lon} = result;
                setLat(lat)
                setLong(lon)
                console.log(lat)
                console.log(long)
                console.log(zip)
                console.log(result)
                return fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + long + "&units=imperial&exclude=current,minutely,hourly,alerts&appid={api}")
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setLoading(false)
                setMaxTemp(data.daily[0].temp.max)
                console.log(lat)
                console.log(long)
                console.log(data)
            })
    }, [zip])

    if (loading === true) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>
    } else return (
        <div>
            <Button zip={setZip}/> <br/>
            High: {Math.round(maxTemp)}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Weather
```

If you want to use the updated state, you'll need to do that in a separate `useEffect` hook with `lat` and `long` in the dependency array.