# Backend API fetch, instead of React

Tags: node.js

I'm new to programming and created a weather app to practice React. I also created a Node server and a homepage (portfolio). So my tree look like this:

project

-portfolio(homepage with simple html file)

-weather(React)

-server.js

Inside the weather app I make a couple of API fetches to openweathermap.org. But it has come to my attention that my API key will be visible when I publish this app and that the best way to avoid that, is to make the call in the Node backend. How do I move data from the weather app to the server.js and vice versa? For example, the user will enter a zip code in the weather app. This zip code is used in the url to fetch the data. How would I make the zip code show up in the server? And then do I just perform all the fetches in the server?

My weather app code can be found at this previous question. I did make the modification suggested and now have two separate useEffect. [React - API fetches - 2nd fetch uses data from 1st fetch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67764141/react-api-fetches-2nd-fetch-uses-data-from-1st-fetch)

Thank you for your help.

server.js

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const path = require("path")
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use("/weather",express.static(path.join("weather/build")))

app.use("/",express.static(path.join("portfolio")))

app.listen(port, () => console.log("Working"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using API keys on your frontend, it will always be exposed to anyone who checks your network requests. If you insist on using the API key with frontend requests, you should atleast use the .env module in your React frontend and add your API keys there, making sure you commit your .env to your .gitignore so it won't get committed to your source code.

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000
```

I'm assuming you already know how to set this up since you're using it here.

**OR**

You could just reverse proxy your request with your API endpoint, store your API keys in your .env, and have your route make the API request to `openweathermap.org`-- successfully hiding your API keys from network analysis:

- React **Weather App** => `YOUR_API_ENDPOINT`
- `YOUR_API_ENDPOINT` =>
  `openweathermap.org`
- `Parse data` => `Send response` to **Weather App**

> How do I move data from the weather app to the server.js and vice
> versa? For example, the user will enter a zip code in the weather app.
> This zip code is used in the url to fetch the data. How would I make
> the zip code show up in the server? And then do I just perform all the
> fetches in the server?

Pass it as a param in the url of the request and have your backend parse out the params from the url.

Weather App:

```
axios.get(`${YOUR_API_ENDPOINT}/zip/${DYNAMIC_ZIP_CODE_DATA}`) //basic example
```

Node

```
app.get("/zip/:zip", (req, res) => {
  console.log('params: ', req.params.zip)
  const zip = req.params.zip;

  //make the API request here and pass in the zip
  res.send(req.params)
})
```